# Scrapy spidermon exceptions

Tags: scrapy, spidermon

I'm trying to setup the basic suite of **spidermon** monitors as described [here](https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/monitors.html#is-there-a-basic-scrapy-suite-ready-to-use) I did a quick Google search and also found [this](https://github.com/scrapinghub/spidermon/blob/master/spidermon/contrib/scrapy/monitors.py). So I made a quick `monitors.py`, then copy and pasted the code in there.

I then proceeded to do this:

```
SPIDERMON_ENABLED = True

SPIDERMON_SPIDER_CLOSE_MONITORS = (
    'spidermon.contrib.scrapy.monitors.SpiderCloseMonitorSuite',
)
```

in my settings.py in the scrapy project.

It keeps raising this error:

```
spidermon.exceptions.NotConfigured: You should specify a minimum number of items to check against
```

Which I believe I've done (`SPIDERMON_MIN_ITEMS = 10 # "SPIDERMON_MIN_ITEMS"` - at the top of the file).

What am I doing wrong? I just want to setup the pre-defined monitors and then optimize them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spidermon couldn't find a valid value for `SPIDERMON_MIN_ITEMS` in the settings. This must be an integer value bigger than zero otherwise it'll throw the error described. `SPIDERMON_ADD_FIELD_COVERAGE` set is also mandatory in order to use all the monitors available in this MonitorSuite.

In order to run the built-in close MonitorSuite `SpiderCloseMonitorSuite` from Spidermon project, please confirm if the `settings.py` file - located in the root directory of your scrapy project - have the variables below:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
   'spidermon.contrib.scrapy.extensions.Spidermon': 500,
}

SPIDERMON_ENABLED = True

SPIDERMON_MIN_ITEMS = 10
SPIDERMON_ADD_FIELD_COVERAGE = True

SPIDERMON_SPIDER_CLOSE_MONITORS = (
    'spidermon.contrib.scrapy.monitors.SpiderCloseMonitorSuite',
)
```

Comment: thx! It works now